# How to add leading zeros to macro variable?

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I am trying to make a loop to do the same query on a set of tables with one table a year, from 2008 to 2020:

```
%macro sqlloop(start,end);
%DO year=&start. %TO &end.;

PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE WORK.RESULT_&year
 SELECT DISTINC ID
 FROM YEAR_&year.
QUIT;

%END;
%mend;

%sqlloop(start=8, end=20)
```

The issue is that I need a leading zero for the 2008 and 2009 tables, because their names are : YEAR_08, YEAR_09, YEAR_10...

Comment: Why not just use 2008 to 2020?  Would not only eliminate the need for leading zeros it also would remove the ambiguity caused by not including the century in your year values.

Comment: I did not choose how tables are named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Z format to generate numbers with leading zeros.

```
%do year=8 to 20;
   %let year=%sysfunc(putn(&year,Z2.));
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%do year = 2008 %to 2020;
  %let y2 = %substr(&year,3,2);
```